# Custom route change for download URL

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.4

I am trying to change my download file route so it can stay protected by adding a non-existing folder "/protected/"

My realpath is

> "/var/www/html/var/uploads/Statements/2019-06/export-1.csv"

and in the end I need it to be:

> "http://app.local:8080/protected/uploads/Statements/2019-06/export-1.csv"

I tried various versions but my code doesn't return wanted path.

Can some help with editing my code:

```
    $file = realpath($file);
    $projectDir = $this->container->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();
    $webDir = realpath($projectDir);
    $finalPath = substr($file, strlen($webDir));

    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

    $downloadUrl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath() . '/' . $finalPath;

    return $downloadUrl;
```

$downloadUrl works as it should but $finalPath is not well formated.

Comment: Use a controller and specify the route you need, and into controller paste your code and return the File instead of an URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping your uploads in the `public/` folder, you should keep them somewhere outside the public document root of the web server, as this is a potential security risk, i.e. someone might get them without going through the mechanism. You could for example have a directory next to `public/` called `data/uploads`. This will ensure files are not reachable by the web server.

In your Symfony project you could create a DownloadController that takes a path or filename as argument and then appends it to the folder:

```php
class DownloadController extends AbstractController
{
    // This should be the path you store your files in
    private $uploadDir;

    public function __construct(string $uploadDir)
    {
        $this->uploadDir = $uploadDir;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/protected/uploads/{file}", name="download", requirements={"file"=".+"})
     */
    public function index(string $file)
    {
        return new BinaryFileResponse($this->uploadDir . $file);
    }
}
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html and https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files

You might have to make some clean ups and sanity checks, e.g. when the file is missing or someone wants to trick you into downloading something outside the base directory, but roughly this should be it.

Now instead of creating pseudo links, in your application you can just call, e.g. in your template:

```
{{ path('download', { 'file': 'Statements/2019-06/export-1.csv' }) }}
```

This will create a proper download link inside your application. You could also create a mapping from a virtual file name, e.g. a hash to the actual file name inside that controller action. You only have to keep track of the references somehow. You can also add access checks, or download counters on that action.

To recap, assuming your project is in `/var/www/myproject`, the web server's public directory is `/var/www/myproject/public/` and your files are kept in `/var/www/myproject/data/uploads/`. The uploaded file then is in `/var/www/myproject/data/uploads/Statements/2019-06/export-1.csv` and the URL will look like this: `http://app.local:8080/protected/uploads/Statements/2019-06/export-1.csv`. By changing the path of the route annotation you can simply adjust the URL without having to move a single file.